# how to deliver QA Automation code?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, automation

I am having a QA Automation framework for an web application using selenium and java,testng in Eclipse as a maven project.
I am using cvs for code versioning among the team.
I need to deliver the updated latest code to the manual testing team for usage. They just change the testdata, and execute the corresponding scripts using the .xml files(Test files are kept in xml files).
Is there a way/tools which hides my code from them?

Answer (score 0):

Compile your code and export as a jar file, which contains only the .class files

Create a batch file, which executes your driver script as required

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this,

Use a batch file to run your program

Create a txt file and copy below code:-

```
java -cp ./ws.jars/*;./bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

In above code ws.jars is a folder which contain all jars which is being used in your project.

Now rename the txt file and change it's extention as .bat.

after click on it bat will run classes according to your testng.xml file.
You can also delete the src folder as TestNG need only bin means class folder.

While I am afraid you can't do same with maven as maven use src/test folder for execution.

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should possibly set up a build server such as Jenkins. This will allow you to link your CVS to Jenkins. It will also allow you to let the manual testers pass in any parameters via the Jenkins GUI.

This will keep your code hidden (within reason) although hiding code from the QA team doesn't seem like the best approach. If you are the person in charge of the Jenkins server, it will also allow you control of who has access to the server and also who can execute and run the tests.